# Thymeleaf Array Element Join

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

**My Array is as follows:**

```
members_array = [{'nickname':'mike','age':'21'},{'nickname':'dan','age':'30'}]
```

**Objective** is to join the nickname elements of the array.

```
${#strings.arrayJoin(members_array ,',')}
```

**Result:**

```
{nickname=mike,age=21},{nickname=dan,age30}
```

**When in fact what i really want is just**

```
mike, dan
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is your use case? Are you trying to create a separate array variable with the nicknames only or are you just trying to iterate over the nicknames? Because you can iterate over just the nicknames without having to change the members_array variable.

Comment: If you really want to use Thymeleaf, as @JohnKim, noted, you should be able to simply iterate over the array using `th:each`. Alternatively, you could create a String[] (or just a concatenated String) in Java code (again using a for loop or similar) and pass that to your Thymeleaf view.

Answer (score 3):

Use Collection Projection for this.

```
${#strings.arrayJoin(members_array.![nickname], ',')}
```